# Extract firstname and lastname, but firstname max length

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to get the first and last name, but the maximum in the first name is 30 characters

```
declare @name nvarchar(250)='David Judith and Holofernes Equestrian of Gattamelata'

SELECT LEFT(rtrim(@name), LEN(rtrim(@name)) - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(rtrim(@name)))) 'firstName'

SELECT RIGHT(rtrim(@name), CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(rtrim(@name)))-1) 'lastName'
```

result of my attempt:

- Firstname=David Judith and Holofernes Equestrian of
- Lastname=Gattamelata

the end result I want:

- Firstname=David Judith and Holofernes
- Lastname=Equestrian of Gattamelata

That is, it must be placed after 30 characters in the last name.

try again, now i need to optimize this code below:

```
    declare @name nvarchar(250)='David Judith and Holofernes Equestrian of Gattamelata'
    SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@name, ' ');
    DECLARE @firstName as NVARCHAR(50)='';
    DECLARE @lastName  as NVARCHAR(50)='';
    DECLARE @value     as NVARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @NamesCursor as CURSOR;
    SET @NamesCursor = CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY FOR
    
SELECT value
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@name, ' ');

    OPEN @NamesCursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM @NamesCursor INTO @value;
     WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        print @value
        print  len(@firstname) 
 if (len(@firstname) < 30 and len(isnull(@firstname,'') + @value) < 30)
            set @firstname=isnull(@firstname,'') + @value + ' '
        else 
            set @lastName=isnull(@lastName,'') + @value + ' '
    
        print @firstname
         FETCH NEXT FROM @NamesCursor INTO @value;
    END
    CLOSE @NamesCursor;
    DEALLOCATE @NamesCursor;
    select rtrim(ltrim(@firstname)) 'First Name', rtrim(ltrim(@lastName)) 'Last Name'
```

thanks

Comment: This is likely going to be an edge-case nightmare; I would suggest you address the root problem which is one of normalisation. You are storing multiple data elements concatenated in a single column - if you expect to deal with the element separately, like you do here, then your data model should be normalised and each atomic value should be in its own column - then your problem ceases to exist.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I understand your point of view, but the problem is that this is due to the synchronization between 2 systems, one of which has two fields and the other a single field